# Are citations the same as references in IEEE?

Tags: style, citations, scientific-publishing

It appears that the word citation and references are use interchangeably. Are they the same thing?

https://www.ieee.org/documents/ieeecitationref.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IEEE uses a style that is common for journal articles and academic works.  The *citation* is the full "description" of the work -- author, title, date, publication, etc.  The document you linked describes the citation styles for various kinds of works and calls them "citiation standards".

The *reference* is the in-text pointer to a citation.  While a citation might be:

> [3] Bovik, H. Q., "Parallel Languages for Parallel Universes," Otherworldly Computing, 3(391-407),1990.

The reference would look something like:

> On the other hand, Bovik [3] asserts that parallel languages have the following properties...

Confusingly, citations are usually listed at the end of the paper in a section called "References", though sometimes you see "Works Cited".  If IEEE has guidelines for the title of this section, I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Monica Cellio is not quite correct.

1. The heading for the list of references is "References". The *[IEEE Editorial Style Manual](https://www.ieee.org/documents/ieeecitationref.pdf)* clearly labels this section with that heading:

   > [image]

   and

   > [image]
2. As the title of that section indicates, it contains references:

   > [image]
3. Many of the terms have multiple meanings, both according to IEEE usage and elsewhere:

   A **source** is a document from which you cite.

   A **citation** is

   a. the act of quoting text from a source

   b. the quotation

   c. the act of refering to the source of the quotation

   d. the reference

   A **reference** is

   a. a mention of a source of information

   b. the source

   In short, the terms *source* and *reference* can be used interchangeably, and the terms *citation* and *reference* can be used synonymously, but they can also mean different things.

---

## tl;dr

In IEEE usage, the words "citation" and "reference" sometimes mean the same things, sometimes not.